# Why I can't fetch special field from json Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I have model class for getting list of jobs from api which contains arrayList with objects as another class-model that describe job model:

```
class JobModel(@field:SerializedName("company_name")
               @field:Expose
               val company_name: String, @field:SerializedName("lastdate")
               @field:Expose
               val lastdate: String, @field:SerializedName("id")
               @field:Expose
               var id: Int, @field:SerializedName("position")
               @field:Expose
               var position: String?, @field:SerializedName("location")
               @field:Expose
               val location: String, @field:SerializedName("job_link")
               @field:Expose
               val job_link: String, @field:SerializedName("seen")
               @field:Expose
               val isSeen: Boolean, @field:SerializedName("in_notepad")
               @field:Expose
               val in_notepad: Boolean, @field:SerializedName("original_url")
               @field:Expose
               val original_url: String)
```

then, I have to get one more field from json response which is called `"contact_data"` as JsonObject. So, I added this field to my job-model class:

```
class JobModel(@field:SerializedName("company_name")
               @field:Expose
               val company_name: String, @field:SerializedName("lastdate")
               @field:Expose
               val lastdate: String, @field:SerializedName("id")
               @field:Expose
               var id: Int, @field:SerializedName("position")
               @field:Expose
               var position: String?, @field:SerializedName("location")
               @field:Expose
               val location: String, @field:SerializedName("job_link")
               @field:Expose
               val job_link: String, @field:SerializedName("seen")
               @field:Expose
               val isSeen: Boolean, @field:SerializedName("in_notepad")
               @field:Expose
               val in_notepad: Boolean, @field:SerializedName("original_url")
               @field:Expose
               val original_url: String, @field:SerializedName("contact_data")
               @field:Expose
               val contact_data: JsonObject)
```

the list of jobs can be shown at RV with adapter. And I could get all data from json and show it at my RV. **BUT** right now after adding one more field I can't show any data at my RV. I thought that maybe problem is located in another place different from model class and didn't manage to find it. So, I decided to comment lines which contains the new field and as a result I saw all info at my RV. What can cause such problem and how I can solve it?

P.S. If you need, I will add some more useful info, but please say me what you need.

Comment: Do you use database in your project? If so, it could be because of migration. You need to increase your version of DB

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov, I don't use any DB at my app, I take all data from server

Comment: check your logs and see if there is any error... if you can also post your json response here

Comment: @Ogbe, I don't receive any errors, and I also see income json, but I can't fetch any data from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make another class for the keys in the contact_data object

```
class contactData(@field:SerializedName("conact_name")
           val contact_name: String,
 @field:SerializedName("contact_number")
               val contact_number: String)
```

and then instead of JsonObject refer to this class name with the contact_data serialized key.

```
 @field:SerializedName("contact_data")
               @field:Expose
               val contact_data: contactData
```